# Chrome keeps telling me, "Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled"

Tags: support

For some reason Stack Overflow keeps telling that it works best when JavaScript is enabled, but Chrome has JavaScript enabled in its settings.

> Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled

I use Chromium 12.0.742.112 on Ubuntu, and Chrome 13.0782.220 on Windows; both have the same issue.

Comment: It seems to work here, on 12.0.742.112 (90304) Ubuntu 11.04. Make sure that you don't have a site specific exception for Stack Overflow.

Comment: It seems that my settings are correct. I don't have any exceptions set and javascript is enabled.

Comment: @Oded why not leave as a bug but [meta-tag:status-norepro]? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - As an obsolete browser, I could simply delete too. But this isn't an SE bug, but a browser config issue.

Answer (score 6):

It works for me. Are you sure you didn't set the browser not to allow Stack Overflow to run JavaScript? Do you have any extension that could avoid JavaScript is loaded for Stack Overflow?

[image: screenshot]

In recent Google Chrome versions, you need to go to the Chrome preferences, click on "Show advanced settings..." at the bottom of the setting page, and then find "Content settings..." under *Privacy*.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: -1 for no red freehand circles.

Comment: @American those look fairly freehand. I'm guessing it's Skitch.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Yes, I use Skitch to take screenshots from my Mac. He was pointing out the circles are not red, though. `:)`

Comment: Fuschia /= red. *shakes head*